# Advice on how to handle logs with Azure App Service Linux

Tags: java, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics

So I've got a few applications run in Azure App Service. Most importantly I've got an executable jar running the majority of the application code. It is currently running as an app service with the Java 11 stack - I have deployed the jar file using Azure Devops and Azure will run this jar within its java 11 container.

The problem I have at the moment is with the application logs. I used to able to ssh onto the vm running the code and check the tomcat logs (before moving to azure app service). I also had ELK installed on the vm although a lot of the time I would just prefer to ssh on and grep and view the logs straight from the vm.

Now all I can do is access the log stream. This will stream the logs as they come out but if I want to search for an error from yesterday I am unable to do so. I've contacted microsoft support who haven't been very helpful so far. I've tried using application insights but I'm not sure how this allows me to better view my logs.

Clicking he application logging tab doesn't allow me to do much - I think it has more features for windows app.s

What I'm ideally looking for is maybe a way to mount a storage account and write the logs there? Or some simple log analytics would do which would enable me to view the logs from the day before or search them. Anyone able to recommend what they do in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started?tabs=maven

Comment: So I did have a look at that. This documentation is not clear on how to setup for a web app. Looking at the documentation it seems that this link is the recommended up to date way of doing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent . So with a web app would I deploy this jar as well and then point to this agent in the jvm args?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is as simple as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent) mentioned. Just deploy this jar as well and then point to this agent in the jvm args.

Please let me know if you have any issues.